# Error when knitting github_document: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, shields.io

I'm generating a README.md GitHub page from a [Rmd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erzk/fnirsr/master/README.Rmd) file. It was generated correctly a week ago but now it's throwing the following error:

> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   README.md --to html --from markdown_github --output README.html
>   --standalone --self-contained --highlight-style pygments --template "C:\Users\E\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\templates\github_document\resources\preview.html"
>   --variable "github-markdown-css:C:\Users\E\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\templates\github_document\resources\github.css"
>   --email-obfuscation none  pandoc.exe: Could not fetch https://img.shields.io/codecov/c/github/erzk/fnirsr/master.svg
>   HttpExceptionRequest Request {   host                 =
>   "img.shields.io"   port                 = 443   secure               =
>   True   requestHeaders       = []   path                 =
>   "/codecov/c/github/erzk/fnirsr/master.svg"   queryString          = ""
>   method               = "GET"   proxy                = Nothing
>   rawBody              = False   redirectCount        = 10
>   responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault   requestVersion       =
>   HTTP/1.1 }  (InternalException (HandshakeFailed Error_EOF)) Error:
>   pandoc document conversion failed with error 67 In addition: Warning
>   message: running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc"
>   +RTS -K512m -RTS README.md --to html --from markdown_github --output README.html --standalone --self-contained --highlight-style pygments
>   --template "C:\Users\E\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\templates\github_document\resources\preview.html"
>   --variable "github-markdown-css:C:\Users\E\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\templates\github_document\resources\github.css"
>   --email-obfuscation none' had status 67  Execution halted

I checked the URL and it works, the badge is also visible on the old [README.md](https://github.com/erzk/fnirsr) file.

As suggested [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/855), I updated rmarkdown and knitr (first to CRAN version, then to GitHub version), but it didn't help.

Then I tried adding `self_contained: no` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284863/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-67). Still throws an error.

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> locale: [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erzk/fnirsr/master/README.Rmd) LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   Kingdom.1252 [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284863/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-67) LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erzk/fnirsr/master/README.Rmd) stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erzk/fnirsr/master/README.Rmd) fnirsr_0.1.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erzk/fnirsr/master/README.Rmd) Rcpp_0.12.8
>   knitr_1.16.3       magrittr_1.5       lattice_0.20-34    R6_2.2.0
>   stringr_1.2.0       [7] dplyr_0.5.0        tools_3.3.2
>   grid_3.3.2         R.oo_1.21.0        RPMG_2.2-1         DBI_0.5-1
>   [13] R.matlab_3.6.1     htmltools_0.3.6    yaml_2.1.14
>   assertthat_0.1     digest_0.6.12      rprojroot_1.2      [19]
>   tibble_1.2         readr_1.0.0        R.utils_2.5.0      evaluate_0.10
>   rmarkdown_1.5.9000 stringi_1.1.2      [25] RSEIS_3.7-4
>   backports_1.0.4    R.methodsS3_1.7.1  Rwave_2.4-5        zoo_1.7-14

I get the same error on Ubuntu 16.04.

I didn't submit it as an issue to knitr yet as there might be a simple solution.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It compiles fine on my machine. Are you maybe behind a proxy or have another network specificity to prevents rstudio from connecting to that url?

Comment: I use a VPN, but it doesn't seem to be the reason for the error. I turned it off and still got the same error. I was still using a VPN last time when the Rmd compiled. I also tried disabling my malware protection software. That didn't help either.

Comment: a related question from today with the same ` (InternalException (HandshakeFailed Error_EOF))`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136481/render-code-for-google-chart-in-rmarkdown-rmd

Comment: see my answer on the question scoa linked to...

Comment: @mb21 your solution worked for me. for some reason the html generated locally is still missing the shield but it looks fine when uploaded to GitHub. feel free to post your answer here so that I can accept it.